# How can a touchdown zone RVR report for one runway be different than the rollout report for the runway going the opposite direction?

Tags: airport, runways, visibility

I saw an RVR report in KSEA where 16C was 800 1200 1800 (touchdown zone, midpoint, rollout), and 34C was 1800 1200 300.  I always thought the same scatterometers used for the rollout side on runway as the touchdown zone in the opposite direction.

Comment: Transmissometers is the term usually used for the devices, rather than "scatterometers" -- don't recall coming across that one. I'd find that result highly suspect as well unless there is a (fourth) "Far End" sensor involved, but I don't think 16C/34C has those. I'd suspect either a transcription error or some difference in time between the readings. Where/when did you see this report?

Comment: I saw the RVR report on the FAA's RVR page on January 19th. https://rvr.data.faa.gov/

Comment: Don't know about this exact case, but since rvr is about contrast, could this be an issue with ambient light or sunlight making the fog brighter in one direction, hence lowering contrast? Like approaching towards sunrise is a lot worse than with the sun behind you